# Oracle how to query a date value and return a value 5 hrs previous to the value queried

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to to query the below column which contains a column of type "TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE".

For some reason (Which isn't all that relevant because this will fix the issue I have in terms of my purposes) every time I insert into that column, I get a value 5 hrs behind. I don't care, so much, if I can get the true time to return from my SQL.

I am trying things like this:

```
SELECT to_char(start_time, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI' ) s_time - (5/24) from table;
```

I keep getting errors that indicate that I am using conflicting data types.

Can anyone please explain how I can get a value 5 hrs previous to the actual value in the column returning in my output please? I've been wrestling with it for some time.

Thank you.

Comment: if you store timestamp with systimestamp then you should test your server settings. Looks like your server is running in the wrong timezone

Comment: Just make sure that whatever you do still works when the server or your local time go into daylight saving time. It could well be anywhere from 7 to 3 hours difference depending on which way you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Use `start_time AT TIME ZONE 'PST'` (or whichever time zone is appropriate to your users) or `start_time AT LOCAL` rather than adding or subtracting a number of hours.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_time TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE );

-- Change the session time zone:
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'PST';
-- Use ISO 8601 formatting for displaying the timestamps
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM';

-- Insert some data.
-- The first row uses the local time zone
-- The second row explicitly specifies the time zone as UTC+01:00
INSERT INTO table_name ( start_time )
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-17 00:00:00'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-17 00:00:00 +01:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

Now if we change the user's time zone:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'UTC';
```

And get the values in the table:

```sql
SELECT start_time,
       start_time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS start_time_pst,
       start_time AT LOCAL           AS start_time_local
FROM   table_name;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> START_TIME              | START_TIME_PST                 | START_TIME_LOCAL              
> :---------------------- | :----------------------------- | :-----------------------------
> 2019-09-17T07:00:00.000 | 2019-09-17T00:00:00.000 -07:00 | 2019-09-17T07:00:00.000 +00:00
> 2019-09-16T23:00:00.000 | 2019-09-16T16:00:00.000 -07:00 | 2019-09-16T23:00:00.000 +00:00
> ```

The data was put in from a `PST` time zone and is now being queried in a `UTC` time zone and has "magically" shifted 7 hours. Okay, there's nothing magic about it ... its the time zone shift and, by default, it isn't showing the time zone of the column without explicitly stating that you want it at a specific time zone.

If you want to select the data in a specific time zone then use `AT TIME ZONE 'PST'` or `AT LOCAL` if you want it in the session's local time zone.

If we alter the session's time zone again:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'EST';
```

And run the same query, we get:

> ```
> SELECT start_time,
>        start_time AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS start_time_pst,
>        start_time AT LOCAL           AS start_time_local
> FROM   table_name;
> ```
>
> ```
> START_TIME              | START_TIME_PST                 | START_TIME_LOCAL              
> :---------------------- | :----------------------------- | :-----------------------------
> 2019-09-17T02:00:00.000 | 2019-09-17T00:00:00.000 -07:00 | 2019-09-17T02:00:00.000 -05:00
> 2019-09-16T18:00:00.000 | 2019-09-16T16:00:00.000 -07:00 | 2019-09-16T18:00:00.000 -05:00
> ```

Again, you can see that the values have changed but by selecting `AT TIME ZONE 'PST'` you get a fixed output regardless of the session time zone and `AT LOCAL` shows the same time (if you adjust for the time zone which its now showing).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5e41cb469de6de9e64c88adff271cd5)*

Answer (score 3):

Addressing only your error, you need to subtract the five hours *before* converting to a string:

```
SELECT to_char(start_time - (5/24), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI') s_time from table;
```

or with an interval instead of fractional days (which leaves it as a timestamp):

```
SELECT to_char(start_time - interval '5' hour, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI') s_time from table;
```

Demo:

```
create table t1 (col1 timestamp with local time zone);
insert into t1 (col1) values (timestamp '2019-09-01 00:00:00 UTC');

alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1 TZH:TZM';

alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/London';

select col1, col1 - 5/24 as col1_adj1, col1 - interval '5' hour as col1_adj2
from t1;

COL1                  COL1_ADJ1             COL1_ADJ2
--------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
2019-09-01 01:00:00.0 2019-08-31 20:00:00   2019-08-31 20:00:00.0

alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';

select col1, col1 - 5/24 as col1_adj1, col1 - interval '5' hour as col1_adj2
from t1;

COL1                  COL1_ADJ1             COL1_ADJ2
--------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
2019-08-31 20:00:00.0 2019-08-31 15:00:00   2019-08-31 15:00:00.0
```

As to why it is (or appears to be) 5 hours out in the first place, because the column data type is with *local* time zone, you see whatever the stored value is in your session time zone. It may just be that you're expecting to see it in the server time zone. Compare the values you see from `systimestamp` and `current_timestamp` - they will probably be five hours apart too.

Some example queries:

Manually adjusting the time probably isn't a good idea. If you must then it might be better to use [`at time zone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Datetime-Expressions.html) to do the adjustment, as that will handle DST if necessary.

```
alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/London';

select col1,
  col1 at time zone 'Africa/Nairobi' as col1_adj3,
  to_char(col1 at time zone 'Africa/Nairobi', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as col1_adj4
from t1;

COL1                  COL1_ADJ3                      COL1_ADJ4
--------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------
2019-09-01 01:00:00.0 2019-09-01 03:00:00.0 +03:00   2019-09-01 03:00:00

alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';

select col1,
  col1 at time zone 'Africa/Nairobi' as col1_adj3,
  to_char(col1 at time zone 'Africa/Nairobi', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as col1_adj4
from t1;

COL1                  COL1_ADJ3                      COL1_ADJ4
--------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------
2019-08-31 20:00:00.0 2019-09-01 03:00:00.0 +03:00   2019-09-01 03:00:00
```

The result is now the same regardless of your local session settings.